# Auto-install nuget package when creating a new vs.net 2015 solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to tell vs.net 2015 to automatically do some actions (like installing nuget packages, copying css files, creating a certain folder stucture, etc...) when creating a new asp.net mvc solution?

I'm new to asp.net mvc, so please be nice!

---

**Small clarification**

What I actually want is to have a certain setup auto-made with **any new project**, as opposed to just restoring missing packages for an **already created** solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**NuGet Package Restore**](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore)

> To promote a cleaner development environment and to reduce repository
>   size, NuGet Package Restore installs all referenced packages before a
>   project is built. This widely-used feature ensures that all
>   dependencies are available in a project without requiring those
>   packages to be stored in source control (see Packages and Source
>   Control on how to configure your repository to exclude package
>   binaries).

Comment: Wait, I think I may have claimed victory too soon. What I actually want is to have a certain setup auto-made with **any new project**, as opposed to just restoring missing packages for an **already created** solution.

Comment: @TheDude https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx check this